# Errors with making a Function parameter a Function with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I am trying to make a Function parameter a Function with multiple parameters

This First Function's parameter is a function with only one parameter

First Function:

```
void execute_and_time(const string& method_name, double(method)(double), double num)
```

This Second Function's parameter is a function with 2 parameters and this is causing errors like:

```
prog.cpp:50:65: error: expected ',' or '...' before '(' token
 void execute_and_time2(const string& method_name, double(method)((double),(double)), double num, double p) {
```

Second Function:

```
void execute_and_time2(const string& method_name, double(method)((double),(double)), double num, double p)
```

Comment: why the extra parentheses?

Comment: try change from ((double),(double)) to (double,double)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I was just trying to fix it because without parentheses it gives the error: "method' declared as function returning a function"

Comment: Huh what please? Did you mean to use a `std::function` instance correctly?

Comment: wow maxpovver thanks you solved my problem, I guess I didn't try enough solutions

Comment: Consider using [plain old C function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) or `std::function`.

Comment: This is the second dumb question I asked today with a simple solution, wow

Comment: programming is quite challenging when you randomly type "solutions" hoping one of them will work.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I agree

Comment: @IrrationalPerson Don't ask dumb questions in 1st place here please. They are actively degrading the quality of this site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me when I write it like this:

```
void execute_and_time(const string& method_name, double(method)(double), double num)
{
    double test = method(num);
}
void execute_and_time2(const string& method_name, double(method)(double,double), double num, double p)
{
    double test = method(num, p);
}
```

It seems you need to remove the extra parentheses around the functions' parameter types (i.e. `double`).

You should probably write your function parameters as actual function pointers, though, like so:

```
void execute_and_time(const string& method_name, double(*method)(double), double num)
{
    double test = method(num);
}
void execute_and_time2(const string& method_name, double(*method)(double,double), double num, double p)
{
    double test = method(num, p);
}
```

Note `*method`.